# Any reason not to pass request / response as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, response

In express I have a handler for a route ex:

```
router.get(`${api}/path/:params/entrypoint`, routeHandler);
```

In this example 'routeHandler' function has a lot of logic doing various things. I'd like to break 'routeHandler' into smaller methods to ease readability and testability. So instead of:

```
routeHandler(req, res) {
    //many lines of code
}
```

We could have:

```
routeHandler(req, res) {
    helperOne(req, res);
    helperTwo(req, res);
}

helperOne(req, res) {
    //do stuff
}

helper2(req, res) {
    //do stuff
}
```

I am being told not to do this by a coworker who is pretty senior, but I do not understand why. Does anyone know of any issues that can arise by passing the response or request objects into helpers? I can not think of any and google isn't revealing any clear answer.

Thanks!

Comment: you may want to look into [middlewares](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) and how to chain them

Comment: Is everything in `routeHandler` a pure algorithm without any async elements? If so, then there isn't technically any issue doing so. Be mindful of your coworkers phrasing. Repeatedly passing in `(req, res)` across all your smaller functions is a code smell. What can work, if you want to break things up, is to make a class with many small methods. That way you only have to pass in `req` and `res` once and then use them internally as `this.req` and `this.res` throughout all of the methods.

Comment: Your coworker is probably referring to the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and expects only the necessary information to be passed to the helper methods and for the route handler to handle the request and response. The route is responsible for the request and response, the helper methods don't even need to know where the data is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know of any issues that can arise by passing the response or request objects into helpers?

Yes you may run into some problems when passing those parameters, especially `res`. For example you may `res.send` multiple times (one in each function) which will raise an exception.

## Scenario

A more concrete example is this

```
routeHandler((req, res) => {
    helperOne(req, res);
    helperTwo(req, res);
});
```

Based on some conditions, I want to stop and return an error from `helperOne` and not go execute any code from `helperTwo`. My definitions of these functions are like this

```
helperOne = (req, res) => {
    const dataPoint = req.body.dataPoint; // a number for example
    if (number > 10) {
        return res.send("This is not valid. Stopping here...");
    } else {
        console.log("All good! Continue..");
    }
}

helperTwo = (req, res) => {
    res.send("Response from helperTwo");
}
```

Then let's say I do have `req.body.dataPoint = 10`, and I'm now expecting my `routeHandler` to stop after the `return res.send` in the first block of my `if` statement in `helperOne`.

This will not work as expected though, because the `return` will concern only `helperOne` which is the returning function. In other terms *it won't propagate* to `routeHandler`.

In the end an exception will be raised because `routeHandler` will call `helperTwo` and try to send a response **again**.

## Solution

- Don't send `req` or `res`. Just pass the data you need and handle the reponse in your *main* handler
- An even better alternative is to use [Express middlewares](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html). Since you have multiple *"sequential"* handlers, you can chain multiple middlewares, which is closer to the standard Express.JS way

Answer (score 1):

One reason to avoid doing this is that you're tightly coupling your helper functions to `routeHandler`, and encouraging complexity in the helpers. If you break up your helper functions so they only have a single responsibility, it's likely you'll only need to pass in a subset of the request.

Why are you passing in `res`, Are you sending a response from inside the helpers? Without knowing the details of your `routeHandler` implementation, I would see if you could handle logic in the helpers, but have them each return a value and keep the response-sending in the main `routeHandler` function. Here's a simple example:

```
handleRoute('/users/:userID', (req, res) => {
  const { userID } = req.params;
  const idIsValid = validateUserID(userID);
  if (!idIsValid) {
    return res.status(400).send('Invalid user ID!');
  }
  ...
});
```